# Overcoming the wildcard limitation with JSON nested arrays in SQL Server 2016/2019

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2019

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get around the wildcard limitations.

Here's an example I'm working on. I have some PTO request data that I'm trying to parse out.

Each requests has a `requestID`, and each `requestID` can have multiple `paidTimeOffEntries`. Basically if I'm taking a week off, it creates 5 `paidTimeOffEntries` for 1 `requestID`.

What I'm trying to do is simply replicate the wildcard [*] and pull every `paidTimeOffEntries` for every `requestID` for an employee.

Here is my JSON and a simple `SELECT` statement that only pulls the first instance of a request

```
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[{"requestStatus":{"code":"approved","labelName":"Approved"},"totalQuantity":null,"totalTime":null,"requests":[{"requestID":"9200017220875_1","requestUri":{"href":"/time/v2/workers/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/time-off-requests/9200017220875_1"},"requestDesc":null,"requestStartDate":null,"requestStatus":{"code":"approved","labelName":"Approved"},"totalQuantity":{"valueNumber":56,"unitTimeCode":"hour","labelName":"HOURS"},"totalTime":null,"paidTimeOffEntries":[{"timeOffEntryID":null,"paidTimeOffID":"9200017220887_1","paidTimeOffPolicy":{"code":"9200016925931_1","labelName":"PTO - Out of Office"},"entryStatus":{"code":"approved","labelName":"Approved"},"earningType":{"code":"9200016925936_1","labelName":"PTO"},"timePeriod":{"startDateTime":"2020-09-17","endDateTime":"2020-09-17"},"totalQuantity":{"valueNumber":8,"unitTimeCode":"hour","labelName":"HOURS"},"meta":null},{"timeOffEntryID":null,"paidTimeOffID":"9200017220879_1","paidTimeOffPolicy":{"code":"9200016925931_1","labelName":"PTO - Out of Office"},"entryStatus":{"code":"approved","labelName":"Approved"},"earningType":{"code":"9200016925936_1","labelName":"PTO"},"timePeriod":{"startDateTime":"2020-09-18","endDateTime":"2020-09-18"},"totalQuantity":{"valueNumber":8,"unitTimeCode":"hour","labelName":"HOURS"},"meta":null},{"timeOffEntryID":null,"paidTimeOffID":"9200017220877_1","paidTimeOffPolicy":{"code":"9200016925931_1","labelName":"PTO - Out of Office"},"entryStatus":{"code":"approved","labelName":"Approved"},"earningType":{"code":"9200016925936_1","labelName":"PTO"},"timePeriod":{"startDateTime":"2020-09-21","endDateTime":"2020-09-21"},"totalQuantity":{"valueNumber":8,"unitTimeCode":"hour","labelName":"HOURS"},"meta":null},{"timeOffEntryID":null,"paidTimeOffID":"9200017220883_1","paidTimeOffPolicy":{"code":"9200016925931_1","labelName":"PTO - Out of Office"},"entryStatus":{"code":"approved","labelName":"Approved"},"earningType":{"code":"9200016925936_1","labelName":"PTO"},"timePeriod":{"startDateTime":"2020-09-22","endDateTime":"2020-09-22"},"totalQuantity":{"valueNumber":8,"unitTimeCode":"hour","labelName":"HOURS"},"meta":null},{"timeOffEntryID":null,"paidTimeOffID":"9200017220881_1","paidTimeOffPolicy":{"code":"9200016925931_1","labelName":"PTO - Out of Office"},"entryStatus":{"code":"approved","labelName":"Approved"},"earningType":{"code":"9200016925936_1","labelName":"PTO"},"timePeriod":{"startDateTime":"2020-09-23","endDateTime":"2020-09-23"},"totalQuantity":{"valueNumber":8,"unitTimeCode":"hour","labelName":"HOURS"},"meta":null},{"timeOffEntryID":null,"paidTimeOffID":"9200017220885_1","paidTimeOffPolicy":{"code":"9200016925931_1","labelName":"PTO - Out of Office"},"entryStatus":{"code":"approved","labelName":"Approved"},"earningType":{"code":"9200016925936_1","labelName":"PTO"},"timePeriod":{"startDateTime":"2020-09-24","endDateTime":"2020-09-24"},"totalQuantity":{"valueNumber":8,"unitTimeCode":"hour","labelName":"HOURS"},"meta":null},{"timeOffEntryID":null,"paidTimeOffID":"9200017220889_1","paidTimeOffPolicy":{"code":"9200016925931_1","labelName":"PTO - Out of Office"},"entryStatus":{"code":"approved","labelName":"Approved"},"earningType":{"code":"9200016925936_1","labelName":"PTO"},"timePeriod":{"startDateTime":"2020-09-25","endDateTime":"2020-09-25"},"totalQuantity":{"valueNumber":8,"unitTimeCode":"hour","labelName":"HOURS"},"meta":null}],"meta":{"metadataEntitlementCodes":["r","k"],"multiPeriodRequestIndicator":false,"actions":[]},"requestorComment":null,"approvalDueDate":null},{"requestID":"9200022223870_1","requestUri":{"href":"/time/v2/workers/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/time-off-requests/9200022223870_1"},"requestDesc":null,"requestStartDate":null,"requestStatus":{"code":"approved","labelName":"Approved"},"totalQuantity":{"valueNumber":8,"unitTimeCode":"hour","labelName":"HOURS"},"totalTime":null,"paidTimeOffEntries":[{"timeOffEntryID":null,"paidTimeOffID":"9200022223872_1","paidTimeOffPolicy":{"code":"9200016925931_1","labelName":"PTO - Out of Office"},"entryStatus":{"code":"approved","labelName":"Approved"},"earningType":{"code":"9200016925936_1","labelName":"PTO"},"timePeriod":{"startDateTime":"2020-10-22","endDateTime":"2020-10-22"},"totalQuantity":{"valueNumber":8,"unitTimeCode":"hour","labelName":"HOURS"},"meta":null}],"meta":{"metadataEntitlementCodes":["r","k"],"multiPeriodRequestIndicator":false,"actions":[]},"requestorComment":{"entryDateTime":"2020-10-21","commentTxt":"PTO"},"approvalDueDate":null},{"requestID":"9200022915434_1","requestUri":{"href":"/time/v2/workers/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/time-off-requests/9200022915434_1"},"requestDesc":null,"requestStartDate":null,"requestStatus":{"code":"approved","labelName":"Approved"},"totalQuantity":{"valueNumber":8,"unitTimeCode":"hour","labelName":"HOURS"},"totalTime":null,"paidTimeOffEntries":[{"timeOffEntryID":null,"paidTimeOffID":"9200022915436_1","paidTimeOffPolicy":{"code":"9200016925931_1","labelName":"PTO - Out of Office"},"entryStatus":{"code":"approved","labelName":"Approved"},"earningType":{"code":"9200016925936_1","labelName":"PTO"},"timePeriod":{"startDateTime":"2020-10-28","endDateTime":"2020-10-28"},"totalQuantity":{"valueNumber":8,"unitTimeCode":"hour","labelName":"HOURS"},"meta":null}],"meta":{"metadataEntitlementCodes":["r","k"],"multiPeriodRequestIndicator":false,"actions":[]},"requestorComment":{"entryDateTime":"2020-10-26","commentTxt":"PTO"},"approvalDueDate":null}]}]';

SELECT a.*
  FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, '$[0].requests[0].paidTimeOffEntries')
      WITH (
                 paidTimeOffID NVARCHAR(25) '$.paidTimeOffID'
                ,totalQuantity DECIMAL(18,2) '$.totalQuantity.valueNumber'
                ,startDateTime DATETIME '$.timePeriod.startDateTime'
                ,endDateTime DATETIME '$.timePeriod.endDateTime'
           ) a
```

What I'm looking to replicate is this `$[*].requests.[*].requestID` and this `$[*].requests.[*].paidTimeOffID` so I can get all time off requests, and which days off they want to take off

Ideally this is what it would return:

```
requestID        paidTimeOffID    totalQuantity    startDateTime    endDateTime   
9200017220875_1  9200017220887_1  8                2020-09-17       2020-09-17
9200017220875_1  9200017220879_1  8                2020-09-18       2020-09-18
9200017220875_1  9200017220877_1  8                2020-09-21       2020-09-21
9200017220875_1  9200017220883_1  8                2020-09-22       2020-09-22
9200017220875_1  9200017220881_1  8                2020-09-23       2020-09-23
9200017220875_1  9200017220885_1  8                2020-09-24       2020-09-24
9200017220875_1  9200017220889_1  8                2020-09-25       2020-09-25
9200022223870_1  9200022223872_1  8                2020-10-22       2020-10-22
9200022915434_1  9200022915436_1  8                2020-10-28       2020-10-28
```

What's the best advice to tackle this? I'm hoping it's something simple that I'm overlooking. I've done this before, but I've had control how the JSON would be formatted. Unfortunately I have no control over this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten multiple `openjson()` calls like that:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, '$') WITH (requests NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) r
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(r.requests) WITH (paidTimeOffEntries NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) p
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(p.paidTimeOffEntries) WITH (
    paidTimeOffID NVARCHAR(25)  '$.paidTimeOffID',
    totalQuantity DECIMAL(18,2) '$.totalQuantity.valueNumber',
    startDateTime DATETIME      '$.timePeriod.startDateTime',
    endDateTime   DATETIME      '$.timePeriod.endDateTime'
) x
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=53439abdc6514475159de8fff388fceb)**:

```
paidTimeOffID   | totalQuantity | startDateTime           | endDateTime            
:-------------- | ------------: | :---------------------- | :----------------------
9200017220887_1 |          8.00 | 2020-09-17 00:00:00.000 | 2020-09-17 00:00:00.000
9200017220879_1 |          8.00 | 2020-09-18 00:00:00.000 | 2020-09-18 00:00:00.000
9200017220877_1 |          8.00 | 2020-09-21 00:00:00.000 | 2020-09-21 00:00:00.000
9200017220883_1 |          8.00 | 2020-09-22 00:00:00.000 | 2020-09-22 00:00:00.000
9200017220881_1 |          8.00 | 2020-09-23 00:00:00.000 | 2020-09-23 00:00:00.000
9200017220885_1 |          8.00 | 2020-09-24 00:00:00.000 | 2020-09-24 00:00:00.000
9200017220889_1 |          8.00 | 2020-09-25 00:00:00.000 | 2020-09-25 00:00:00.000
9200022223872_1 |          8.00 | 2020-10-22 00:00:00.000 | 2020-10-22 00:00:00.000
9200022915436_1 |          8.00 | 2020-10-28 00:00:00.000 | 2020-10-28 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I was able to use your example and get additional elements figured out.